# Progress Dialog in Glide view

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog, progressdialog, android-glide

I have implemented a Gallery using Glide. My code is as below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

       recyclerView.addOnItemTouchListener(new GalleryAdapter.RecyclerTouchListener(getApplicationContext(), recyclerView, new GalleryAdapter.ClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view, int position) {
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putSerializable("images", images);
                bundle.putInt("position", position);

                FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                SlideshowDialogFragment newFragment = SlideshowDialogFragment.newInstance();
                newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
                newFragment.show(ft, "slideshow");
            }

            @Override
            public void onLongClick(View view, int position) {

            }
        }));

        fetchImages();
    }

    private void fetchImages() {

        pDialog.setMessage("Downloading images...");
        pDialog.show();

        JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                        pDialog.hide();

                        images.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Image image = new Image();
                                image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));

                                images.add(image);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }

                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });

        // Adding request to request queue
        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(req);
    }
```

I have used a progress dialog. Currently, when I open gallery, Dialog comes and disappears after few seconds. Then the activity remains empty. Images get loaded after some time. I want to avoid this. I want to the dialog to stay longer, at least till half of the images load (say 5 out of 10).

Answer (score 0):

put the  `pDialog.hide();` at the end of `onResponse()`, that happen because you are hiding the progress dialog before looping at the result array and setting the data.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to the dialog to stay longer, at least till half of the images
>   load (say 5 out of 10).

If you wanna achieve this, you can hide your `progressDialog` after certain number of iteration according to your need inside `onResponse()`. In that matter you have to notify your adapter about data set change (`notifyDataSetChanged()`) on every iteration.

You can modify your code as below:

```
JsonArrayRequest req = new JsonArrayRequest(endpoint,
                new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                        Log.d(TAG, response.toString());                           

                        images.clear();
                        for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {
                            try {
                                JSONObject object = response.getJSONObject(i);
                                Image image = new Image();
                                image.setName(object.getString("name"));

                                JSONObject url = object.getJSONObject("url");
                                image.setSmall(url.getString("small"));
                                image.setMedium(url.getString("medium"));
                                image.setLarge(url.getString("large"));
                                image.setTimestamp(object.getString("timestamp"));    
                                images.add(image);
                                if(i > 5){                       // Here is a change
                                    pDialog.hide(); 
                                }

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                        }
                        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();  // Updated
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                pDialog.hide();
            }
        });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am unable to see the result as the images itself are not loading! Why is this problem??

Comment: mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); if(i > 5){pDialog.hide();}

Comment: You mean like this ?

Comment: Downloaded images are not displayed in image place holders in Glide.

Comment: I did not get what you are saying. Are you saying like this: mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(if(i > 5){pDialog.hide();}); If not can you modify the answer with correction?

Comment: Images are loading very slowly but again dialog appears before a single image being loaded. If the images are loading slow due to network, dialog should continue to stay till  5 of them loads but thats not happening.

Comment: Please check my Updated answer. You have to put `mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` after the loop as before. `proDialog.hide()` will be positioned as above.